# Faucet connector under sink is leaking

Tags: plumbing

4 years old house had a bathroom faucet corroding so I had a handyman come over to replace it with new one. He stopped the work midway and said that connector between faucet and hose has issue and is leaking. There was no leak problem with old faucet but after he connected the new one, there is significant leak. He said he tried with plumber's tape but it's not helping and left the job and wanted me to work with plumber to work next steps as probably the connector is bad. Anything I can do to check before calling a licensed plumber now?[image]

Comment: For a 4 year old house, this should have been a warranty item if the faucet corroded to the point of needing to be replaced. The plastic shutoff valves don't inspire confidence in quality of work on the original build, to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, I did get the free replacement faucet from Moen(Faucet manufacturer)

Comment: Those look like plastic shut of valves with an integrated hose. That's... bizarre! I was about to tell you to replace the whole thing yourself (this is a DIY site, after all!), but that's a MESS! Get your plumber to put in proper shut off valves with threaded connections, then run a standard, threaded connection at _both_ ends hose between the shut off valves and the inlets to the faucet. DIYing this would require purchasing the tools to make PEX-A connections and those are quite expensive for just two fittings. Probably makes more financial sense to hire this one out.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to be **sure**, other than "handyman not competent as a low-rent substitute for a plumber" since teflon tape does less than nothing for that type of joint. *They broke it, they should pay to fix it, but when you hire the unlicensed and uninsured you often get stiffed on the part where they take responsibility for their mistakes.*

**Likely** they cross-threaded the plastic connector on the brass sink part.

Could be as simple as turn off the supply, unthread the connector, thread it back on straight, but if they damaged the threads sufficiently you might need a new hose, as getting the correct threads to engage when someone has plowed ahead and cut a whole new set of incorrect threads in the plastic by not stopping to fix the cross-threading is difficult.

The good news is that it's unlikely for the brass threads to have been damaged by the plastic ones, so it's $10 hose, not a $100 faucet that got ruined.

Comment: definitely cross threaded, and in fact, it looks like they took a wrench to that fitting

Comment: Thanks for the response. I certainly learned few things in process. Handyman was definitely not skilled and probably made more mess than help. I am in process of finding a plumber who can do this right. Unfortunately builder also went with cheap push-pull plastic valve so hose can't be changed in isolation and needs to be changed with the valve where it's hard connected.

Comment: Sadly, this looks like it's more than just replace a $10 hose. The hoses seem to be integrated into the shutoff valves! What a trap to ensure future work for plumbers!